# What are the properties of the domain and image of the matrix exponential $e^A$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-exponential

I know that for real numbers $\exp(x)$ is defined for every real $x$ and that the result is always greater than zero. I want to compare that to the case $\exp(A)$ where $A$ is a square matrix.

Is it defined for every possible $A$?
Does every matrix can be a result of $\exp(A)$?

I have the feeling that every result of $\exp(A)$ is nonsingular but it could be that I only checked specific cases.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: My hypothesis that the result is always nonsingular is true if det(exp(A)) = exp(s) where s is the sum of all eigenvalues of A. And this appears to be the case.

Comment: Off the top of my head, I would say that the equation in complex matrices $e^X=A$ has solutions if and only if $\dim\ker A=0$, and that the equation in real matrices $e^X=A$ has solutions if and only if $\dim\ker A=0$ and, for all $\lambda<0$ and $k\ge1$, the number of Jordan blocks of size $k$ for the eigenvalue $\lambda$ is even.

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. There are comprehensive articles on matrix exponentials https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential and matrix logarithms https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm_of_a_matrix in Wikipedia which contain answers to your questions. Yes, the exponential of a matrix is always non-singular and $\det \exp A = \exp(tr \, A)$.

Comment: $e^A e^{-A} = I$

Comment: For a complex $A$, we can write $A=e^B$ **iff** $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I didn't consider checking the Wikipedia page one the subject. All of my questions were answered there.